# Stuck Trying to Abstract Something, am I attempting to over simplify?

Tags: java, abstraction

I'm Working with a bunch of tasks, each of these tasks have some amount of Parameters that they use. Some of these parameters are required, others are optional, and some tasks have parameters that other tasks will not have/ever use. The way the system is currently built, each Task has it's own Parameter Class. so example. `FileIngestionTask.java` has a `FileIngestionTaskParams.java`.

Right now there are about 6 tasks, but there will definitely be more added on in the future so I'm attempting to make a generic ParamValidator. 
Before the task attempts to execute I have to run `X` number of checks, something like...

```
if (FileInjestionTaskParams.getFilePath() == null){
    logError(X)
```

But then another task I'll need to verify

```
if (UpdateShippingFileParams.getFilePath() == null){
    logError(X)
```

Before this system switched to a set Parameter class(for each task), we were using a `map(String, Object)`, so I had a generic Parameter Validator, each class would just `setRequired(FILE_PATH)` and in the parameter validator I could do something like

```
if (required(FILE_PATH)){
    if (Map.get(FILE_PATH) == null) {
        log error
}}
```

Is there any way for me to do this using the param classes? I originally thought of using a base param class that all `TaskParams` extended, but not all tasks use or need the same Parameters. So i couldn't just have `baseParam.getFilePath`. I looked a little into Reflection but I'd prefer not to go down that route if a better way exists.

Comment: Have each parameter class include a `validate()` method that validates it as proper for that particular parameter?

Comment: Yes but that still involves me writing it in each parameter class. They are technically just data objects, should they be in charge of validating their parameters?

Comment: I would have those params classes implement a common interface, like `class FileIngestionTaskParams implements FileParams`.  Then in your validator, check the params object using `instanceof`, and inside the if-block, cast it.  No reflection needed.

Comment: Well, who should be in charge of validating them if not the objects themselves? Why should that task be coupled with anything?

Comment: But hypothetically if they have say.. 15 parameters. Would it be bad to have a class implement 15 paramaters?

Comment: I think you have to validate the parameters somewhere.  If they're all different, then you have to have a different class/method to do the validation.  There really aren't any shortcuts here.

Comment: I do see one potential savings -- `FileInjestionTaskParams` and `UpdateShippingFileParams` are both type `ParameterClass`?  You could make a single abstract base class for all Tasks that performs basic validation.  `if (taskParams.getFilePath() == null)` then only change that in derived classes if it differs.  Might save you some work.

Answer (score 0):

In java 8, we could do something like this.

```
public class FooParam
{
    public String filePath(){ ... }
    public Long   fileSize(){ ... }

--

public class FooTask
{
    public void setValidators(Validator<FooParam>... validators){ ...

--

    fooTask.setValidators(
        Validator.requires   (FooParam::filePath),
        Validator.greaterThan(FooParam::fileSize, 1024) 
        ...
    );

--

public interface Validator<T>
{
    public void validate(T t) throws Exception;

    public static <T> Validator<T> requires(Function<T,?> prop)
    {
        return t->
        {
            if(prop.apply(t)==null)
                throw new Exception();
        };
    }
    public static <T> Validator<T> greaterThan(Function<T,Long> prop, long value)
    ...
```

The basic idea is to use method references, instead of names of properties.

Something more generic is helpful too

```
    Validator.of( p->p.fileSize()>1024, "file too small" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is if you are literally talking about options like command line options, then [Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html) has that problem solved for you.

```
// create Options object
Options options = new Options();

// add t option
options.addOption("t", false, "display current time");

Option logfile   = OptionBuilder.withArgName( "file" )
                                .hasArg()
                                .withDescription(  "use given file for log" )
                                .create( "logfile" );

Option logger    = OptionBuilder.withArgName( "classname" )
                                .hasArg()
                                .withDescription( "the class which it to perform "
                                                  + "logging" )
                                .create( "logger" );

Option listener  = OptionBuilder.withArgName( "classname" )
                                .hasArg()
                                .withDescription( "add an instance of class as "
                                                  + "a project listener" )
                                .create( "listener");
```

Etc.